# Problems Connecting to Azure VM through RDP via VPN

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have a azure virtual network setup in Azure's North Europe data centre. I can connect to all VM's in the network via a public IP address without an issue. We have just started using a VPN to connect to the VM's to increase security but I can connect to some VM's in out network but I cannot connect to others.

The network setup in the windows firewall configuration seems to be the same for each machine yet I can connect to VM2 but not VM1.

Has any one seen this problems before>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally discovered the problem, I had the servers setup on 10.6.0.0/16 and the VPN client on 10.7.0.0/16. I had to enable RDP on each of the servers firewall in the azure management console to allow traffic from 10.7.0.0/16 (ie the VPN).